# Not able to grab the second array element

Tags: javascript

```js
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {

  var word = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    var firstWord = strs[i];
    var secondWord = strs[1 + i];
    if (strs[i].length >= secondWord.length) {
      for (var d = 0; d < strs[i].length; d++) {
        var store1 = firstWord[d];
        if (secondWord.indexOf(store1) != -1) {
          word += store1;
        } else {
          word = "";
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (var f = 0; f < strs[i + 1].length; f++) {
        var store2 = firstWord[f];
        if (firstWord.indexOf(store1) != -1) {
          word += store2;
        } else {
          word = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return (word);
};
```

I am trying to check the characters of two words in an array and store it in.

Issue, my secondWord is not able to grab the second element of array strs

strs = ["flower", "flow", "character"]

Comment: do you have any errors? What do you mean by not able to grab - is secondWord empty?

Comment: Can you edit the snippet to add a `console.log` of your function with some input? Off the top though, you're doing a `.length` operation on an `i + 1` element which will give an error eventually once you reach the end of the string

Comment: @painotpi No point in making that a code snippet if executing it does nothing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example values that you are calling the function with, and the expected results you want to get for them.

Comment: @Maksat Rahmanoc                                                                                            
          TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that it aims to write a function that compares the letters in the elements of the array and **collects the common** ones, I wrote a code like this. I hope it works for you.

```js
strs = ["flower", "flow", "character"]
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) { // function to find common letters in words.

  var word = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < strs.length-1; i++) { //2 times
    var firstWord = strs[i];
    var secondWord = strs[1 + i];
    if (firstWord.length >= secondWord.length) { // true for flower and flow
      for (var d = 0; d < firstWord.length; d++) { //6 for flower
        var store1 = firstWord[d];
        if (secondWord.indexOf(store1) != -1) { //if secondWord contains char from firstWord
          word += store1;
        } else {
          //word = "";
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (var f = 0; f < secondWord.length; f++) {
        var store2 = secondWord[f];
        if (firstWord.indexOf(store2) != -1) {
          word += store2;
        } else {
          //word = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return (word);
};
console.log(longestCommonPrefix(strs))
```